# dying chilli plants

Tags: houseplants, plant-health, pruning, chili, repotting

I have a few chilli plants. initially 4 or 5 of them were in a same pot.
Quickly they grew quite big and really strong and I thought it's time to move them to different pots and so I did.

I repotted them and pruned them.

However, after 3-4 days most of my plants are dying specially the stronger ones.
The smaller ones, I didn't prune. They are perfectly healthy and growing new leaves.
I have attached a photo here.

What could be the reason? Thanks again !

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If this is the example of your pruning it is the pruning that killed your chilies.  Plants make their own food.  Via photosynthesis.  When you cut off all the photosynthetic factories (chlorophyll in green leaves) that plant is essentially starved.  It is unable to make carbohydrates for growth and reproduction.  and that red pot looks like it doesn't have drainage.  What kind of soil did you use?  Fertilizer?  Make sure the peppers still alive have potting soil, drainage, a little fertilizer and allow the soil to dry out a bit before watering again.

Comment: Tha plant did have leaves after pruning. However they have dries up and dropped. The red pot has holes under it. I made the holes drilling. The soil I am using is cocopeat.

Comment: Good for you!  Drilling holes works just fine.  Cocopeat means coconut husk coir and peat moss?  Sterilized?  I think you took off too many leaves.  I would take those plants in the red pot and cut them back to a live outward facing bud.  Transplant them in a much smaller pot and moisten the soil, allow to dry out a bit before watering again.  It would be best if the soil was sterilized 'potting medium' with no added fertilizers or water holding gimmicks like sponges and gels.  Cocopeat might work.  The stems are actually photosynthesizing, they are green.  Not a lot but some.

Comment: no, the soil is not sterilized. Sorry I couldn't understand what it means "cut them back to a live outward facing bud". Could you please explain it a bit?

Comment: Sure Srijani.  If you look at the stems you can see 'nodes'.  At those nodes you should also be able to see a swollen 'bud'.  These buds will grow into branches or leaves.  You want to promote only those buds that are on the outside of the branch.  You don't want branches or leaves growing towards the center.  Cut just above a bud, leave an 1/8 of an inch of stem above the bud, angle the cut so water flows off the cut and down the backside of the stem to protect the bud from excess water.  It looks as if you've got nice healthy buds about ready to put out photosynthetic factories very soon.

Comment: Send a better picture and I can help you decide which buds to choose.  I'd like to see a different angle so I can see the buds on the other side of the stem.  What an interesting pot.  It is shaped to fit your little table? I think the coir and peat moss is fine for potting but a bit too acidic for peppers.  Are you able to buy sterilized potting soil?  Peppers need more sun than you can get indoors without artificial grow lights.  Perhaps you might think about setting yourself up with a 'grow room'?  Peppers take a lot of high intensity wide spectrum light that can't be had through a window.

Comment: Don't be afraid to tell me you still don't understand, okay?  We could go to chat and if you send more pictures, I can 'graphically' albeit very non CAD oriented...show you where to cut and why.  Check out potting soil, are you able to purchase?